# Define containing a deferred object

Tags: dojo

About require instruction, Dojo official doc says:

> if a configuration object is provided, it is passed to the configuration API as described >in Configuration. Next, the dependencies listed in dependencies (if any) are resolved. >Finally, callback (if any) is executed with the resolved dependencies passed in as >arguments

With my example (below), I want to use users.json data in main program, but callback of the called module (monModule.js) is not executed and I obtain an empty object.
How can I proceed ?
Thanks to you.

1 )Main program (extract)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(["monModule"],function(monModule){
        console.log(monModule);// returns {}
    });
</script>
```

2) Called module (monModule.js) :

```
define(["dojo/request/xhr","dojo/json"],function(xhr,json){
    xhr("users.json",{handleAs:"JSON"}).
    then(function(data){console.log(return data;});
});
```

3) users.json

```
[
{‘ id’:"id1",’nom’:"nom1"},
{ ‘id’:"id2",’nom’:"nom2"},
{‘id’:"id3",’nom’:"nom3"}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

the call in the then is also async so that is why you are getting back an empty object.  you will have to add another deferred to your module for it to run and a then in your code

```
define( ["dojo/request/xhr","dojo/json" , "dojo/Deferred"], function( xhr, json , deferred) { 


                var def = new deferred();
                xhr("users.json", { handleAs :"JSON" }).then( 
                    function( data ) { 
                        return def.resolve(data);
                    }
                );


        return def.promise;;
});
```

And in Code get it by

```
  require(["custom/monModule"],function(monModule){
        monModule.then(function(users){
            console.log(users); 
        });

    });
```

Comment: OK, it works perfectly, thanks to you. But I want to avoid the "then" in main program. DOJO doc tells us that all dependencies of a require are resolved and associate callbacks executed when they are called in the callback function of the require. An idea ?